# Sitecore error while rebuilding the search index

Tags: search, lucene, sitecore

I'm facing with an interesting issue. I've got the below error when I wanted to rebuild one of my Search Indexes.

It worked many times before, but now it failed. The other indexes like master, web ... works fine.

I use Sitecore.NET 7.0 (rev. 140408), the error is:

```
Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=BlablaSearchIndex|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
at Lucene.Net.Store.IndexInput.ReadString()
at Lucene.Net.Index.SegmentInfo..ctor(Directory dir, Int32 format, IndexInput input)
at Lucene.Net.Index.SegmentInfos.Read(Directory directory, String segmentFileName)
at Lucene.Net.Index.SegmentInfos.AnonymousClassFindSegmentsFile.DoBody(String segmentFileName)
at Lucene.Net.Index.SegmentInfos.FindSegmentsFile.Run(IndexCommit commit)
at Lucene.Net.Index.SegmentInfos.Read(Directory directory)
at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.Init(Directory d, Analyzer a, Boolean create, IndexDeletionPolicy deletionPolicy, Int32 maxFieldLength, IndexingChain indexingChain, IndexCommit commit)
at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter..ctor(Directory d, Analyzer a, Boolean create, MaxFieldLength mfl)
at Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex.Reset()
at Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex.PerformRebuild(IndexingOptions indexingOptions)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
at (Object , Object[] )
at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)
```

Can anybody give me some help? Or just a tip where should I find the solution?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen the Lucene index get corrupt many times and cause similar issues during a rebuild.  You could try deleting the relevant directory (by default it will by in the Data/Indexes folder) and triggering a rebuild again.